# Получение массива с объектами

Tags: javascript

`введите сюда код`Мне нужно получить массив с объектами в таком виде(см. код). Я частично реализовал, но в итоге застрял, подскажте плз решение. Может намного проще есть метод решения. Попрошу обратить внимание в результирующем объекте на значения.

```js
let dataTable = {
    header: ['group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3'],
    body: [
      {
        name: 'item1',
        values: ['42', '52', '21'], //данные из массива относятся к item1
      },
      {
        name: 'item2',
        values: ['63', '21', '35'],
      },
      {
        name: 'item3',
        values: ['86', '31', '15'],
      },
    ],
  };
let header = Object.values(dataTable.header)
var body = Object.values(dataTable.body)

let result = header.map(name => {
    var nameBody = body.map((body) => body.name)//[item1, item2, item3]

    return { 
    name: name,
    [`${item}`]: //ну вот тут не понимаю как все item-ы получить и их value
}
})

//============================необходимый результат
  {
    name: 'group 1',
    item1:  42,
    item2:  63,
    item3: 86,
  },
  {
    name: 'group 2',
    item1: 52,
    item2: 21,
    item3: 31,
  },
  {
    name: 'group 3',
    item1: 21,
    item2: 35,
    item3: 15,
  },
];
```

Comment: У вас числа не совпадают в исходной структуре и целевой. Это опечатки или с числами нужно что-то делать?

Comment: Упс, сейчас подправлю

Comment: количество элементов в headers и в  values - гарантированно совпадает?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что числа из массива с `name: 'item1'`  в результате перераспределяются между ключами `item1`, `item2`, `item3`?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, вообще по логике должно было быть по другому :-)

Comment: Вроде бы, если только эти имена не просто заглушки, которые на ходу меняют значение.

Comment: ключ name значение не меняет, а его значение может менятся, в то время как iключи tem1, item2...менятся могут

Comment: Простите, не понимаю. Спрошу по-другому: действительно ли в первый объект массива должны попасть числа 42, 52, 21, а не числа 42, 63, 86?

Comment: Да, должны попасть числа 42, 52, 21. Я просто не понимаю вообще каким образом их можно передать) массив с числами, где item1 - это все значения item1 и как видно они используются в объектах ниже

Comment: То есть, скажем, 'item2' из исходной структуры никак не связано с 'item2' в результирующей? Потому что в 'item2' в результирующей могут попадать числа из всех 'item' исходной?

Comment: не совсем, в item2 попадают эти значения values: ['63', '21', '35'], выглядит таким обраом:
[{
item2: 63
},
{
item2:21
},
{
item2: 35
}
]

Comment: Но ведь у вас в примере результата не так, там в item2 другие числа.

Comment: Прошу прощение! Кажется ночное время сказывается на моей внимательности

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так

```js
let dataTable = {
    header: ['group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3'],
    body: [
      {
        name: 'item1',
        values: ['42', '52', '21'], //данные из массива относятся к item1
      },
      {
        name: 'item2',
        values: ['63', '21', '35'],
      },
      {
        name: 'item3',
        values: ['86', '31', '15'],
      },
    ],
  };
let header = dataTable.header
var body = dataTable.body

let result = header.map(
(name, index )=> body.reduce( 
(acc,item)=> 
{ 
  acc[item.name] = item.values[index]; 
  return acc;
}, {name})
  
)

  console.log(result)
```

или вот тоже самое чуть покороче запись

```js
let dataTable = {
    header: ['group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3'],
    body: [
      {
        name: 'item1',
        values: ['42', '52', '21'], //данные из массива относятся к item1
      },
      {
        name: 'item2',
        values: ['63', '21', '35'],
      },
      {
        name: 'item3',
        values: ['86', '31', '15'],
      },
    ],
  };
  
let h = dataTable.header
var b = dataTable.body

let result = h.map((name, i)=>b.reduce((a,it)=>(a[it.name]=it.values[i], a), {name}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Благодарствую!)

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант:

```js
const dataTable = {
    header: ['group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3'],
    body: [
      {
        name: 'item1',
        values: ['42', '52', '21'],
      },
      {
        name: 'item2',
        values: ['63', '21', '35'],
      },
      {
        name: 'item3',
        values: ['86', '31', '15'],
      },
    ],
};
const header = Object.values(dataTable.header);
const body = Object.values(dataTable.body);

const newData = header.map((name, i) => {
  const object = { name };
  for (const item of body) {
    object[item.name] = item.values[i];
  }
  return object;
});

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!